# How can I send the member name when a user tag someone

Tags: python, discord.py, mention

I'm making a discord bot with Python and I want to send an embed when the use use the command **]kill** .So when I tag someone and use the command the output is not the member name.

[image: output]

I need to make it the tagged user's name.

This is my code.

```
killgifs = ['https://c.tenor.com/1dtHuFICZF4AAAAC/kill-smack.gif' , 'https://c.tenor.com/gQAWuiZnbZ4AAAAC/pokemon-anime.gif' , 'https://c.tenor.com/PJbU0yjG3BUAAAAd/anime-girl.gif' , 'https://c.tenor.com/Re9dglY0sCwAAAAC/anime-wasted.gif']


@bot.command(name='kill')
async def kill (ctx,person) :
  author = ctx.author
  embed = discord.Embed (color=discord.Color.red())
  embed.set_author(name=f'{author} kills {person}')
  embed.set_image(url = (random.choice(killgifs)))
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with `discord.Member` here since you can't mention a person in an embed title/author field. Simply change your code to the following:

```py
killgifs = ['https://c.tenor.com/1dtHuFICZF4AAAAC/kill-smack.gif',
            'https://c.tenor.com/gQAWuiZnbZ4AAAAC/pokemon-anime.gif',
            'https://c.tenor.com/PJbU0yjG3BUAAAAd/anime-girl.gif',
            'https://c.tenor.com/Re9dglY0sCwAAAAC/anime-wasted.gif']


@bot.command(name='kill')
async def kill(ctx, person: discord.Member): # Make the person a discord.Member
    author = ctx.author
    embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red())
    embed.set_author(name=f'{author} kills {person.display_name}') # Display the name
    embed.set_image(url=(random.choice(killgifs)))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```